# Hiding id of another page when read more button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with description and read more button in it(4 same div). when the read more button is clicked it will direct to the page which displays the full description of all the 4 divs . when a read more of a particular div is clicked i want to direct to the page with all the contents, but but it should only display the full description of that particular div and hide other divs description

HTML CODE

one.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
$(".a1 a").click(function()
$("#a2_bio").hide();
$("#a3_bio").hide();
$("#a4_bio").hide();
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<style type="text/css">
p
{
font-size:12px;
font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
text-align:center;
}
.a1, .a2, .a3, .a4
{
width:300px;height:200px;float:left;
margin-left:30px;
border:1px dotted #CCCCCC;
padding:1px;
background:#CCC;
}
.images
{
width:100px;
height:75px;
margin:0 auto;
border:1px #666 solid;
margin-top:30px;
background:#C36;    
}

.a1 a, .a2 a, .a3 a, .a4 a
{
float:right;
margin-right:10px;
width:75px;
height:20px;
font-size:11px;
color:#060;
}
</style>

<div class="a1">
<div class="images"> </div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<a href="two.html#a1_bio"> Read more </a>
</div>

<div class="a2">
<div class="images"> </div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<a href="two.html#a2_bio"> Read more </a>
</div>

<div class="a3">
<div class="images"> </div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<a href="two.html#a3_bio"> Read more </a>
</div>

<div class="a4">
<div class="images"> </div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<a href="two.html#a4_bio"> Read more </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

two.html

```
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
#a1_bio, #a2_bio, #a3_bio, #a4_bio
{
width:800px;
height:200px;
background:#CCC; 
border:#666 1px solid;
margin-bottom:20px !important;
float:none;
margin:0 auto;
}

#a1_bio p, #a2_bio p, #a3_bio p, #a4_bio p
{
font-size:12px;
font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;   
}
</style>
<div id="a1_bio">
<p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>

<div id="a2_bio">
<p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>

<div id="a3_bio">
 <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>

<div id="a4_bio">
<p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can accept the answer if it serves your requirements so that other  users can get help.

Comment: Updated my code check it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/T7WLC/)**

**JS**:

```
 var hashes = window.location.hash;
 $(hashes).show();
```

**CSS**:

```
 #a1_bio, #a2_bio, #a3_bio, #a4_bio
    {
    width:800px;
    height:200px;
    background:#CCC; 
    border:#666 1px solid;
    margin-bottom:20px !important;
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:none;
    }
```

Comment: i need to place the JS inside the ready function in two.html?

Answer (score 1):

you can try using following JS on ready(in two.html, hide all divs by default, and in one.html use url like : two.html?url=a2_bio):

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,    
    function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
var divId = getUrlVars()["url"];
$('#'+divId).show();
```

Comment: may i know what error you are getting or what you have tried?